# How to use this.state with react-native?

Tags: react-native

Hi I'm new to react so bear with me.
Below is my code...

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight, AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            myLeader: 'Joe',
        };
    }

    onPress(){
        alert({this.state.myLeader}); // 14
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}>          
                    <Text>{this.state.myLeader}</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

How to fix this problem?

error message is this. 'this is a reserved word(14.9) at Home.js:14.9'
I want to use {this.state.myLeader} in

```
onPress(){
    alert({this.state.myLeader});
}
```

I tried 'bind(this)'
Any clue why?

Comment: onPress(){
        alert(this.state.myLeader);
    } // it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with your usage of `{}`. In the context of JSX, `{}` can be used to "interpolate" a value within it. But if you're writing plain JavaScript code (as in `alert({this.state.myLeader})`) you don't need to interpolate anything, you just pass the value `this.state.myLeader` to `alert`, as in `alert(this.state.myLeader)`.

Regarding the usage of `alert` within React Native, you'll probably want to follow [@kytwb's advise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47492896/275442) and use `Alert.alert`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace line 14 with:

`console.log(this.state.myLeader)`

To use Alert with React Native, take a look at [the doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html).

Answer (score 0):

First, import Alert from react-native:

`import { StyleSheet, Alert, Text, View, TouchableHighlight, AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';`

Then, change the onPress function:

```
onPress(){
    Alert.alert(this.state.myLeader); // 14
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to forget about the bind and do this:

```
 onPress = () => {
        alert({this.state.myLeader}); // 14
    }

 <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPress}>
```